# Does a differentiable $f[g(x)]$ imply a differentiable $g(x)$ or the reverse?

Tags: calculus

Does a differentiable $f[g(x)]$ imply a differentiable $g(x)$?

Does a differentiable $g(x)$ imply a differentiable $f[g(x)]$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all. Take $f$ to be the $0$ function, so that $f\circ g$ is readily differentiable, regardless of how nasty $g$ is. By the same token, let $f$ be any non-differentiable function, and let $g$ be the identity function, so that $f\circ g=f$ is non-differentiable, even though $g$ is differentiable.

Comment: Three answers in ten seconds, all the same.

Comment: @dfeuer Great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 1):

Both are not true.

$$f(x) = 0, \quad g(x) = \text{Some weird function}$$

$$f(x) = \text{Some weird function}, \quad g(x) = x$$

Answer (score 1):

Can you come up with an $f$ such that $f\circ g$ is *always* differentiable? Can you come up with $f$ such that $f\circ g$ is not differentiable for $g(x)=x$?